# ORDER siblings BY and rownum while migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I am migrating one project from Oracle to PG and have a problem with one sql query.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE descriptor_value (
    descriptor_value_id bigint NOT NULL,
    descriptor_group_id bigint NOT NULL,
    full_value varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
    short_value varchar(250),
    value_code varchar(30),
    sort_order bigint NOT NULL,
    parent_value_id bigint,
    deleted smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    portal smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ;
```

This is the original oracle query that I am migrating:

```
select rownum as ROW_NUM, DESCRIPTOR_VALUE_ID 
         from DESCRIPTOR_VALUE
         connect by prior DESCRIPTOR_VALUE_ID = PARENT_VALUE_ID
               start with PARENT_VALUE_ID is null
                      and DESCRIPTOR_GROUP_ID = (select DESCRIPTOR_GROUP_ID
                                                   from DESCRIPTOR_VALUE
                                                  where DESCRIPTOR_VALUE_ID = 867)
               order siblings by SORT_ORDER;
```

And this is my postgresql query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descriptor_values AS (
            SELECT
                    ARRAY[descriptor_value_id] AS hierarchy,
                    descriptor_value_id,
                    parent_value_id,
                    sort_order
            FROM
                    descriptor_value
            WHERE
                    parent_value_id IS NULL AND descriptor_group_id = (
                        SELECT descriptor_group_id
                        FROM descriptor_value
                        WHERE descriptor_value_id = 867)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                    descriptor_values.hierarchy || dv.descriptor_value_id,
                    dv.descriptor_value_id,
                    dv.parent_value_id,
                    dv.sort_order
            FROM
                    descriptor_value dv
            JOIN descriptor_values ON dv.parent_value_id = descriptor_values.descriptor_value_id

    ) SELECT
            descriptor_value_id
    FROM
            descriptor_values order by hierarchy;
```

Solution for `order siblings by` I took from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17737560/5182503 . However, the order of the rows in postgresql result set differs from the order in oracle result set. What about rownum here I absolutely stopped. Could anyone help me to build right pg query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you link assumes there is a natural ordering of the `descriptor_value_id`.

If the `sort_order` is unique on the table, then the below query should work.

If not, then we will have to do some monkey business in the values you put into the `hierarchy` array.

```
WITH RECURSIVE descriptor_values AS (
            SELECT
                    ARRAY[sort_order] AS hierarchy,
                    descriptor_value_id,
                    parent_value_id,
                    sort_order
            FROM
                    descriptor_value
            WHERE
                    parent_value_id IS NULL AND descriptor_group_id = (
                        SELECT descriptor_group_id
                        FROM descriptor_value
                        WHERE descriptor_value_id = 867)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                    descriptor_values.hierarchy || dv.sort_order,
                    dv.descriptor_value_id,
                    dv.parent_value_id,
                    dv.sort_order
            FROM
                    descriptor_value dv
            JOIN descriptor_values ON dv.parent_value_id = descriptor_values.descriptor_value_id

    ) SELECT
            descriptor_value_id
    FROM
            descriptor_values
    order by hierarchy;
```

**Update in response to comment**

Since `sort_order` is not unique across the table, it needs to be incorporated into the `hierarchy` array.  I also added the `row_number()` to the final query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE descriptor_values AS (
            SELECT
                    ARRAY[sort_order, descriptor_value_id] AS hierarchy,
                    descriptor_value_id,
                    parent_value_id,
                    sort_order
            FROM
                    descriptor_value
            WHERE
                    parent_value_id IS NULL AND descriptor_group_id = (
                        SELECT descriptor_group_id
                        FROM descriptor_value
                        WHERE descriptor_value_id = 867)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                    descriptor_values.hierarchy 
                       || array[dv.sort_order, dv.descriptor_value_id]
                    dv.descriptor_value_id,
                    dv.parent_value_id,
                    dv.sort_order
            FROM
                    descriptor_value dv
            JOIN descriptor_values ON dv.parent_value_id = descriptor_values.descriptor_value_id

    ) SELECT
            row_number() over (order by hierarchy), 
            hierarchy,
            descriptor_value_id
    FROM
            descriptor_values 
   order by hierarchy;
```

Comment: @Shtirlits I updated my answer.  Please try the new query and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited this line `descriptor_values.hierarchy  || array[dv.sort_order, dv.descriptor_value_id],`. However, the result in oracle differs from the result on pg. Does you solution suppose that sort_order is inside one parent? For example, if we have parent A that has two children B and C, then childB has sort_order=0 and childC has sort_order=1.

Comment: @Shtirlits  It is supposed to account for the sort order.  Try adding the `hierarchy` column to your output to see what the query does.  Does the hierarchy in your table have more than one root element?  If so, I added `sort_order` to the initial array.

Comment: Thank you very much. You last solution gives the same results as in oracle.